# How to remove additional character from a csv file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file as below

```
Target;Date;Safe;os_version
Box11;01/10/2020T23:58:25Z;abc_test1;Anazon Linux
Box2;02/10/2020T23:58:25Z;xyz_test2;Anazon Linux
Box3;03/10/2020T23:58:25Z;mnp_test3;Anazon Linux
Box11;04/10/2020T23:58:25Z;abc_test1;Anazon Linux
```

In the `date` column field there are some additional detail like eg. `T23:58:25Z` which I would like to remove

I used the below code but it failed:

```bsh
Import-Csv "D:\Dev\test11.csv" | %{ $_.Date = $_.Date -replace "T.*.Z" ; $_}
```

**I am getting this error :**

```
Exception setting "Date": "The property 'Date' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set."
At line:1 char:36
```

**Expected output is**

```
Box11;01/10/20;abc_test1;Anazon Linux
Box2;02/10/20;xyz_test2;Anazon Linux
Box3;03/10/20;mnp_test3;Anazon Linux
Box11;04/10/20;abc_test1;Anazon Linux
```

Comment: command i ran is 
Import-Csv "D:\Dev\test11.csv" | %{ $_.Date = $_.Date -replace "T.*.Z" ; $_}

Comment: `Import-Csv <thefile.csv> -Delimiter ';'`. Without that, PowerShell uses a comma as separator character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-Delimeter` parameter allows you to set the delimeter

```
Import-Csv "D:\Dev\test11.csv" -Delimiter ";"
```